# Make notices in Gutenberg within an AJAX running

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I've a PHP running with AJAX, and I'm wondering how to make notices in Gutenberg.

I've a JS with this code to run the notice:

```
( function( wp ) {
    
    wp.data.dispatch('core/notices').createNotice(
        'error',
        'Message of error',
        {
            isDismissible: true,
            actions: [
                {
                    url: '#',
                    label: 'Button'
                }
            ]
        }
    );
} )( window.wp );
```

But I don't know how to make it run, maybe with a variable or something.
How could make it work?

Comment: Can you give details? When do you the notice to be appear?

Comment: It's a plugin when it's saving the post, it makes some tests, and then, I'd like to show errors if it's necessary

Comment: @David Have you enqueued your JavaScript using the hook `admin_enqueue_scripts()` (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts) in PHP?